# One-to-many then eager load an array with Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

With Laravel and the eloquent ORM, I want to create an array or object of all posts and corresponding comments that belong to a specific user (the logged in one).  The result will then be used with Response::eloquent(); to return JSON.

Basically in pseudo-code:

```
All Posts by user ::with('comments').
```

or

```
Posts by Auth::user()->id ::with('comments').
```

I have my database setup per the usual with a user's table, comments table and posts table.  The comments table has a post_id and the posts table has a user_id.

The long way of doing this without Laravel would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = 'user_id'
foreach($result as $post) {
    SELECT * FROM comments WHERE posts_id =  $post->id
    foreach($query as $comment) {
        $result[$i]->comments[$n] = $comment
    }
}
```

But I want to accomplish it with Laravel's Eloquent ORM.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you don't even need a nested eager load, you just need to modify the query that with returns, so:

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')->where('user_id', '=', 1)->get();
```

You can daisy chain most of the methods in the Eloquent system, generally they're just returning a Fluent query object.

(I haven't tested it but I'm fairly certain that'll work. Also, you can't do it on ::all() because that calls ->get() for you. You have to dig in the source code to find this, I don't think the Eloquent documentation mentions that's what it's doing.)

Also the [Eager Loading Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) covers nested eager loading, so you could load all users, with their posts, with the comments:

> You may even eager load nested relationships. For example, let's
>   assume our Author model has a "contacts" relationship. We can eager
>   load both of the relationships from our Book model like so:

```
$books = Book::with(array('author', 'author.contacts'))->get();
```

Comment: You have to have a Comment class defined and BINGO!  Simple as what you described.

Comment: The eager loading of nested relationships (`author.contacts`) is what I've been struggling with. Thanks!

Comment: [Eager Loading Docs have moved to here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: In response to `Post::with('comments')->where('user_id', '=', 1)->get()`, a more readable solution would be `Auth::user()->posts()->with('comments')->get()`

Comment: Or, if it's not pertaining to `Auth::user()`, you could use `User::find($id)` in it's place.

Comment: note: ['author', 'author.contacts'] is ambiguous, simply using with('author.contacts') will suffice.

Comment: [New link for Eager loading docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)